# R - How show weekdays at x-axis instead of dates when plotting in R

Tags: r

Hi I am working on a Coursera assignment that requires me to do some plotting. My code is working well except one things - my x-axis value is showing date instead of weekdays.

This is my [result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0zXn.png)
And this is the [expectation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rfWG.png)

I guess there's something to do with the date time format at `as.POSIXct(datetime)` in my code but I couldn't find the answers by searching webs. I prefer to use base library to solve this and I haven't touched the ggplot library yet.

Below is my code and appreciate your help.

#Download the dataset

```
      filename <- "exdata-data-household_power_consumption.zip"
```

#Check if dataset existed

```
          if (!file.exists("exdata-data-household_power_consumption.zip"))
{
          fileURL <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/exdata%2Fdata%2Fhousehold_power_consumption.zip"
          download.file(fileURL, filename, method = "curl")
```

}

#Check if folder existed

```
          if(!file.exists("household_power_consumption.txt"))
          unzip(filename)
```

#Load the data

```
      data <-read.table("household_power_consumption.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ";", na.string = "?", check.names = FALSE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,comment.char = "",quote = '\"')
```

#Convert the Date and Time variable to Date/Time class

```
      data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

#Select the data from 2007/02/01-2007/02/02

```
         data <- subset(data, data$Date >= '2007-02-01' & data$Date <= '2007-02-02')
```

#Combine the Date and Time

```
      datetime <-paste(data$Date,data$Time)
```

#Add Datetime to original data

```
      data$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(datetime)
```

#Setting a 2 by 2 diagram

```
      par(mfrow = c(2, 2), mar = c(4,4,2,1))
```

#Plot the diagram

```
      plot(data$Global_active_power~data$DateTime, type="l",ylab = "Global Active Power (kilowatts)", xlab="")
      
      plot(data$Voltage~data$DateTime, type="l",ylab = "Voltage", xlab="")
      
      with(data, {plot(data$Sub_metering_1~data$DateTime,type="l", ylab = "Energy sub metering", xlab ="")
                lines(data$Sub_metering_2~data$DateTime, col="red")
                lines(data$Sub_metering_3~data$DateTime, col="blue")})
      legend("topright", col=c("black","red","blue"), legend = c("Sub_metering_1", "Sub_metering_2", "Sub_metering_3"), lty =1
      ) 
      
      plot(data$Global_reactive_power~data$DateTime, type="l",ylab = "Global_reactive_power", xlab="")
```

#Export the PNG file

```
          png(filename = "plot4.png")
          dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [lubridate package](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/make_datetime.html) is very convenient for handling dates and is nice for plotting time series.

You don't provide an MRE, but using a pre-installed dataset, here is a simple example where you just need to add a column with `make_date()`. In this case, it defaulted to week day.

Here's what the air quality dataset looks like:

[image]

```
# Load dataset
data(airquality)

# Load libraries
library(lubridate)

# Filter for the first week of July as an example
df <- subset(airquality, Month == 7 & Day <= 7)

# Create a date format column using lubridate's make_date
# Note: This dataset is known to be for year 1973, so it is hard-coded
# here; use your year column instead
df$Date <- with(df, make_date(1973, Month, Day))

# Plot 
plot(df$Date, df$Wind,
     type = "l", # Draw lines only
     col = "blue",
     xlab = "Date",
     ylab = "Wind Speed (mph)",
     main = "Wind Speed in New York - First Week of July 1973"
     )
```

Which produces:

[image]

If you don't like the default x-axis label, you can suppress it in the plotting and then modify. Here's an example with the full weekday name.

```
plot(df$Date, df$Wind,
     type = "l",
     col = "blue",
     xlab = "Date",
     ylab = "Wind Speed (mph)",
     main = "Wind Speed in New York - First Week of July 1973",
     xaxt = "n") # Suppress the default x-axis

# Custom x-axis
axis.Date(1, at = df$Date, format = "%A") # weekday full name
# axis.Date(1, at = df$Date, format = "%a") # weekday abbreviated
# axis.Date(1, at = df$Date, format = "%b %d") # month-day
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To transform a date into the name of the day (Monday, Tuesday, etc.), you can use the `format()` function, like this:

```
date <- '2024-02-02'

date2 <- as.Date(date)

format(date2, "%A")

# [1] "Friday"
```